# Transfer app Test filght

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have an app uploaded on Testflight which has been expired from my developer account. I want to upload the same app to Test flight from another company developer account. Will it create a conflict?

There is no transfer option in Testflight mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already read the documentation, you can find it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Key points to highlight in your case would be:

- Make sure your accounts aren’t in a pending or changing state.
- The App must have had at least one version that has been released to
  the App Store

The last point is the most troublesome but it happens -_-